# Flutter SQFLite asset database

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, sqflite

I had an MYSQL Dumped database which I converted to SQLite and moved that into the assets folder in Flutter.

I am trying to open the database but it is throwing the following error:

```
E/SQLiteLog(29199): (8) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA user_version = 1] attempt to write a readonly database I/flutter (29199): error DatabaseException(attempt to write a readonly database (code 8 SQLITE_READONLY)) sql 'PRAGMA user_version = 1' args []} during open, closing...
```

Here is the code:

```
_initDatabase() async {

    var databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var path = join(databasePath, "example.db");

    var exists = await databaseExists(path);

    if (!exists) {
         print('creating a new copy from asset!');

     try {
         await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
     } catch (_) {}

     ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "example.db"));
     List<int> bytes =
      data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
   } else {
      print('opening existing database');
}

return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, readOnly: true);
```

}

It doesn't throw an error in the above method but when I try to query (a simple SELECT for example).

I have searched similar questions but of no avail. Some are saying it is a permission issue and some are saying something different.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Databases should not be in Assets. Assets are read only compiled into the binary of the app. Not sure if that is your only problem but I would start with that.

Comment: The official example of sqflite is doing the same, putting the database in assets folder. See https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md

Comment: Ah sorry I just read your description text and error but didn't actually read your code. Yeah copying the database to the phones storage then trying to access it should be a valid approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a version during `openDatabase` is to perform database schema migration, hence not for read only mode. Just remove the `version` parameter and you should be fine:

```dart
await openDatabase(path, readOnly: true);
```